# no se puede convertir de 'void' a un 'System.Action'

Tags: c#, windows-forms, async-await

Estoy tratando de convertir a asincrono, tengo un botón, que al presionar me genera un backup de una base de datos mysql, y quisiera que sea asíncrono, pues abecés demora y no se sabe hasta cuanto, pues allí insertare un loading.

pues si mi función MySqlConnection no llevara parámetros, pues me funciona con normalidad, pero son necesarios esos parámetros, Help Me.

o tal vez alguna otra manera de solucionar mi problema.

```
private async void btnGenerarBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var file = "";
        var conn = "server=" + txtServer.Text + ";user=" + txtUser.Text + ";password=" + txtPassword.Text + ";database=" + txtDb.Text;
        var nombre = (DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + "-"
            + DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + "-"
            + DateTime.Today.Day.ToString() + "_"
            + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "-"
            + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "-"
            + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());

        var dir = txtFile.Text;
        file = dir + "\\" + txtDb.Text + "_" + nombre + ".sql";
        //aqui es el error
        Task oTask=new Task( MySqlConnection(conn,file));

        await oTask;


    }
    public  void MySqlConnection (string conn,string file)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        mb.ExportToFile(file);
                        con.Close();

                        MessageBox.Show("Se genero con exito su backup", "Mensaje de Confirmación ");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta enviando una funcion lambda al constructor y dentro del lambda ejecutas el metodo asi:

```
 Task oTask =new Task(()=>{
   MySqlConnection(conn,file);
 });
//..
```

En la forma en como lo hace, le estas pasando el resultado de la funcion MySqlConnection esa funcion no retorna nada, te lanza el error.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pues también lo intente, y aplique su sugerencia, y aparentemente no hay error, pero en el fondo no me esta llamando la función, reemplace por la versión normal sin async await, y si funciona.

pues no se que estaría pasando.